# Alternatives for $(this).text() when setting a variable in GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

As I have multiple events I will push based on the selector, I have created a function:

```
function trackEvent(primary,trigger,selector,event,ec,ea,el,ev) {

jQuery(primary).on(trigger, selector,event function(e) {
        dataLayer.push({
          "event" : event,
          'event_category': ec,
          'event_action': ea,
          'event_label': el,
          'event_value': ev
        });
});

}
```

I call the function like this:

```
trackEvent(document.body,'mousedown', '#top_nav_link_1','event','Top Navigation','Click',$(this).text(),'0');
```

I am setting the 'ec','ea', and 'el' with values but want to grab the name of the element using

```
$(this).text()
```

This is all located within a GTM Custom HTML Tag:

```
<script>
  
function trackEvent(primary,trigger,selector,event,ec,ea,el,ev) {

jQuery(primary).on(trigger, selector, function(e) {
        dataLayer.push({
          "event" : event,
          'event_category': ec,
          'event_action': ea,
          'event_label': el,
          'event_value': ev
        });
});

}

trackEvent(document,'mousedown', '#top_nav_link_1','event','Top Navigation','Click',$(this).text(),'0');

</script>
```

When this runs, everything works perfectly EXCEPT, I get no value for event_label.

[image]

Since, I'm moving this code from one tag manager to another, I don't understand why it's not compiling correct. It is working in the other tag manager, but not in Google Tag Manager.

Any thoughts on what could be the cause?

Comment: `$(this).text()` is evaluated when `trackEvent(...)` is called, and `this` refers to the current context in which `trackEvent(...)` is called. If you want the target element's text, you need to call `const el = $(this).text();` *inside* the anonymous function you're using as event handler, right before you're pushing to `dataLayer`: https://jsfiddle.net/c2Lq9a3d/

Comment: This did in fact work. Unfortunately, sometimes I will need to set "el" based on different criteria. But, knowing that I can call $(this).text() from within the function helps immensely!

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid you'd say that :) Here's a revised version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/c7x9g8bj/